# library is not created using makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am getting gcc: error: libs1.a: No such file or directory error when I am trying to create a library in a make file. I don't know where I am going wrong. The library command is write becasuse I tried troubleshooting and independently ran the command and it create the library.  Makefile below....

```
COMPILER = gcc
CCFLAGS = -Wall
all:search

debug:
    make DEBUG=TRUE

search.o: search.c tokenizer.h uthash.h
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c search.c

tokenizer.o: tokenizer.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c tokenizer.c

libs1.a: tokenizer.o search.o
    ar -cvq libs1.a search.o tokenizer.o

search: search.o tokenizer.o
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -o search search.o libs1.a

ifeq ($(DEBUG), TRUE)
 CCFLAGS += -g

endif

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.a libs1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
search: search.o tokenizer.o
```

to

```
search: search.o libs1.a
```

That will make `search` dependent on `libs1.a` and `make search` will make `libs1.a` before doing the link.

Note that you have search.o in both your lib and your link line. You probably want or the other, not both.